# mxgraph rubberband select above unselectable vertex

Tags: javascript, mouseevent, mxgraph

I have an image icon I am using as the background of the graph. (I am not using the graph background function because I need the background resize as I zoom and the background need to move back and front of the graph.) The image icon is set as not selectable and not movable

I want to use the mxRubberband for multiple select of the other icon. However, the mxRubberband is not working as I start selecting from above the background icon. (It works if I remove that.) How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found the solution. Simple press "Alt" button while selecting. Or initialize the graph mxGraph.prototype.isForceMarqueeEvent to return true.